# How to improve the performance of the package

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization, plsql

I have been asked to improve the package performance without affecting the functionality.How to start with optimisation ?Any suggestions

Comment: Start by posting what you want to optimize...

Answer (score 1):

In order to optimize PL/SQL programs you need to know where they spend time during execution.

Oracle provide two tools for profiling PL/SQL. The first one is DBMS_PROFILER. Running a packaged procedure in a Profiler session gives us a breakdown of each program line executed and how much time was spent on each line. This gives us an indication of where the bottlenecks are: we need to focus on the lines which consume the most time. We can only use this on our own packages but it writes to databases tables so it is easy to use. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABDACHA).

In 11g Oracle also gave us the Hierarchical Profiler, DBMS_HPROF. This does something similar but it allows us to drill down into the performance of dependencies in other schemas; this can be very useful if your application has lots of schemas. The snag is the Hprofiler writes to files and uses external tables; some places are funny about the database application writing to the OS file system. Anyway, [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_profiler.htm#ADFNS023).

Once you have your profiles you know where you need to start tuning. The PL/SQL Guide has a whole chapter on Tuning and Optimization. [Check it out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#CHDJJAGH).

> " without affecting the functionality."

Depending on what bottlenecks you have you may need to rewrite some code. To safely change the internal workings of PL/SQL without affecting the external functionality(same outcome for same input) you need a comprehensive set of unit tests. If you don't have these already you will need to write them first.